# Add a class to the first teaser on /blog page

Tags: 7, nodes

On a site I'm developing the first blog teaser on the blog index page */blog* is displayed bigger than the other teasers. I do this with a class *'featured'*, can I add a function in *template.php* to add this class to the first blog teaser on the */blog* page?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Is the /blog page an actual page or is it just an archive/listing of posts on that url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [template_preprocess_node](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) hook you can use `$vars['id']` to get the array index in the order that the nodes are printed.

You'll need to replace **COND_FOR_BLOG** with whatever logic you have for checking that.

Example to get you started:

```
function THEME_OR_MODULE_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if (COND_FOR_BLOG && $vars['id'] == 1) {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'featured';
  }
}
```

**Edit:** Note that `$vars['id']` is not zero-based so `$vars['id'] == 1` actually gives the first post.